# How can we pass dates dynamically to events in a responsive calender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am currently using `w3widgets responsive calendar` plugin in my `java spring MVC web application`. I have been able to load events on `ajax`, but unable to pass dates dynamically to the events in responsive calender.
http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/

I am initialising the calender as

```
 $('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar
 ({
  time: '2013-05',
    events: {
      "2013-04-30": {},
      "2013-04-26": {}, 
      "2013-05-03": {}, 
      "2013-06-12": {}}

});
```

In the above code, how can i pass the dates dynamically?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', 
{
   "2013-04-30": {"number": 5, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar"},
   "2013-04-26": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com"}, 
   "2013-05-03": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-error"}, 
   "2013-06-12": {}
})
```

You can pass 2 argument `edit` and other is object of `updatedevents` ...

Hope this will help you.